# Reading and writing files using mex

Tags: c++, matlab, iostream, ifstream, mex

I'm using windows visual studio. I want to read in a .txt file in C++ using mex. Here is the minimal example:

```
#include <mex.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

ifstream data; 

return;
}
```

When I run `mex test.cpp` in matlab, I get the following error.

> Error using mex test.cpp
>
> G:\test.cpp(35)
>
> : error C2065: 'ifstream' : undeclared identifier
>
> G:\test.cpp(35)
>
> : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'data'
>
> G:\test.cpp(35)
>
> : error C2065: 'data' : undeclared identifier

I'd also like to output a .txt file, but similar error occurs when I try `ofstream`. From what I see, I think matlab is not recognizing the headers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

What can I do to read/write files in mex? Is there another way of reading/writing files in mex other than iostream and fstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been solved. I realized I just forgot to add `using namespace std`. Can't believe I've spent many hours trying to figure this simple mistake.